# Usage of "at" in "... at the cottage just over my shoulder is where they had been growing cannabis"

Tags: sentence-structure, inversion

Here's [a British news report](https://youtu.be/wqKBD_yz6d0):

And this is what I've transcribed:

> Well, last August when it was found that Neil and Yvette Hartley had...had been growing almost 90 cannabis plants, little did their neighbours know **that** in this quiet corner -- this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside, **at** the cottage just over my shoulder is where they had been growing cannabis.

I do hear ***at*** before *the cottage*, but in that case, I don't know how to figure out the structure of the ***that***-clause.

Is this some kind of inversion?

Comment: The same structure as in **I know that you are right**.

Comment: I think it's just a mistake by the speaker. The clip is not from a broadcaster, it's from the Daily Mail (a right wing newspaper, not noted for its high English standards).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The words are fine, but the punctuation is poor. Insert another dash and it makes good sense: "... in this quiet corner - this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside, at the cottage just over my shoulder - is where …". It would be better to delete the "in" before "this corner," IMO.

Comment: @alephzero - Agreed about the punctuation, but remember, this is the OP's transcription of an (probably) unprepared spoken commentary.

Comment: @alephzero I don't know if you've listened to the clip, but as far as I can tell, the speaker seems to initially utter _in this quiet corner_ and then quickly reutter _this quiet corner_ with _this quiet pretty little corner_. So I think what he's intended to say is like this: _...that in this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside, at the cottage just over my shoulder is where they had been growing cannabis._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Little did their neighbors know
     that 
       in this quiet corner
           —this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside—
       at the cottage just over my shoulder
       is where they had been growing cannabis
```

You can understand **at the cottage just over my shoulder**  as a locative phrase   paralleling **in this quiet corner** and   —*this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside*— as standing in apposition to **this quiet corner**.

It may seem a little odd to have a prepositional phrase stand as the subject of **is**, but it is quite frequent in colloquial speech when the predicate complement is a phrase headed by **where**:

> **At the barbershop down on Main Street is where** I got this lightning bolt shaved on my head.
>
> **In this corner is where** the disobedient child is told to sit. We call it the "time out corner".

So:

> ... in this quiet corner ... at the cottage over my shoulder is where ...

P.S. The same can occur with temporal phrases:

> **On the fourth Thursday of November is when** we celebrate Thanksgiving in the US.

Locative and temporal phrases can be chained together in order to "zero in" on the specific place or time.

> In Philadelphia, in the old section of the city down near the river, on Chestnut Street between 5th and 6th, stands Independence Hall.

Comment: Thanks. I believe  _this quiet corner_ has been replaced with _this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside_. If so, is it correct to say that the _that_-clause starts with the adjunct (_in this quiet pretty little corner in the Kent countryside_) followed by the subject (_at the cottage just over my shoulder_) and then by the predicate (_is where they had been growing cannabis_)?

Comment: Also, is it correct to say that the OP's sentence and all your examples (except for the last one) are not cases of inversion? (I'm sure your last example displays inversion.)

Comment: @listeneva: I think the *that*-clause starts with **in**. A constituent of the prepositional phrase has been "replaced", not the prepositional phrase in its entirety.

Comment: @listeneva: Correct. Only the last sentence **...stands Independence Hall** shows inversion of the normal subject-verb word-order.  I'm not sure what grammarians would call switching the order of **where** and a locative prepositional phrase: *Where I got this lightning bolt shaved on my head is at the barbershop down on Main Street.* versus *At the barbershop...is where...*